# Expressions out of an SQLExecute Task

Tags: sql, ssis, ssis-2012

I have an Execute SQL Task that compares 2 snapshot dates and if the date is greater than a month it returns a 1 else it returns a 0.  If I use an expression to test for one of the expression I get an advancement in the project however if I test for the other I get no return and the process stops.  I have not changed the data so it is testing the same data set.  The following are my expression testing:

```
@[User::MonthFlag] =="1"
@[User::MonthFlag] =="0"
```

The month Flag is what I am using to pass out as my result set. Heres the query I used:

```
if (datediff(mm,@maxdw01,@maxas48)=1) 
begin 
    select 1 as MonthFlag 
end else 
    select 0 as MonthFlag 
End
```

Comment: That is all the information you provide? what is MonthFlag?  this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: The month Flag is what I am using to pass out as my result set.   Heres the query I used:  if  (datediff(mm,@maxdw01,@maxas48)=1)
begin
 select 1 as MonthFlag
end
else 
 select 0 as MonthFlag End

Comment: I save the MonthFlag as a variable

Comment: Just edit your question and add the information, not put it on comment

Comment: Have you defined a default value of "0" or "1" for the MonthFlag user variable in the Variables table?  That would ensure it is never NULL.

Comment: I just set the default value to 1 and it didn't proceed. The task tests fine as long as there is only one expression being verified. If I add the second expression to test it stops. I have done this before even in this package for a different test and it works ok.  I just can't get it to process here.

Comment: Another approach to consider is to run your before mentioned tsql to output the results (include @maxdw01 and @maxas48) to a temporary table and then analyze that.  Setting things up like this as just a temporary means to view your data may reveal an issue that you were not previously aware of and an unexpected rule that may need to be applied in your tsql logic.  Unexpected data issues are common.

Comment: Is the `Else` missing a `Begin` or is that a typo?

Comment: I changed the if statement to this:   select case 
 when datediff(mm,@maxdw01,@maxas48) >=1  then 1
else 0
end as [MonthFlag]
into #tmptblFlag



 select [MonthFlag] from #tmptblFlag
 Drop table #tmptblFlag  Still get the same issue

Comment: Have you confirmed that you are correctly populating the MonthFlag variable?  Try this:  1) set MonthFlag = 'x'  2) run the Execute SQL task that sets the variable  3) check if the variable has changed from 'x' (see [here](http://www.techbrothersit.com/2013/12/ssis-how-to-watch-value-of-variables.html)).

Comment: You are actually not applying two expressions, but multiple options under a single expression.  Even though you are applying an if condition, which could include multiple else if options, it is still considered one expression.

Comment: I have been able to as long as I was evaluating  the expressions I have seen the process react correctly.  However if I test to see if the expression is another value that's when it freezes.

Comment: Have you tried adding the variable to the watch list to view its value?  If you're in the data flow, add an output grid to show the results.  Sometimes under the control flow I'll add a Script Task using C#, pass the variable to it and then just use a MessageBox.Show(["user::MonthFlag"]).ToString()); to display the result to the window in order to see what is taking place and even add more information to this command to tell you which record is having a problem.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that the tsql could be trying to perform a calculation based on a NULL, in which case a NULL will be the result.  Applying the ISNULL function in the tsql could fix this.  Just throwing out additional things to consider with regard to the data, which may explain why your logic worked in other packages but not this.

Comment: I took out the second expression evaluation and changed the data so the expression would be both 0 and then again so it would be a 1.  I then changed the remaining expression evaluation to look for the zero.  It worked.  I then changed the evaluation to look for a 1 and the data to make that expression occur and it worked.  However if I have both evaluations there and I know which path it should take it stops at the task.

Comment: I could not get it to work so I changed the script of one of the next steps to account for the possibility of the month datediff and it is working ok.  Thank you all for your help.  I'm sorry it never resolved.